# Check if form is submitted

Tags: php, html

I am making a calendar web app and when I click on a date a form pops up. If I use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` or `isset($_POST['submit'])` to check whether the form is submitted or not, the `echo` code executes even when I refresh the page and don't click on submit. How can I make sure that the form data is retrieved only when I submit the form?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
                    Event Title:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="eventTitle" id="eventTitle" maxlength="15" size="20" placeholder="Code.fun.do" required><br><br>
                    Event Description:<br>
                    <textarea name="eventDescription" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea><br><br>
                    From:<br>
                    <input type="time" name="eventTimeFrom"><br><br>
                    To:<br>
                    <input type="time" name="eventTimeTo"><br><br>
                    <input id="eventSave" type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<?php
            $eventTitle = $eventDescription = $eventTimeFrom = $eventTimeTo = "";
            //if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
                echo "<h2>something</h2>";
                $eventTitle = test_input($_POST["eventTitle"]);
                $eventDescription = test_input($_POST["eventDescription"]);
                $eventTimeFrom = test_input($_POST["eventTimeFrom"]);
                $eventTimeTo = test_input($_POST["eventTimeTo"]);
            }
            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }
?>
```

Comment: You want to keep the values after submit?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I am using javascript to get form data and display it in the calendar.

Comment: Your question title says something else, and your body something else, can u explain clearly what u want?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Removed that part of the question

Comment: When you are testing the form, are you refreshing the page? This could be re-sending the POST request.

Comment: ok, it echos something even if u dont submit?

Comment: @JohnReid I first load the page. Then I click on a date and a form appears. Then I fill that form and then the page automatically refreshes and echo output appears. Then if I manually refresh the page, then also the echo output appears. So does this mean that if a user submits a form once and then refreshes the page, it will be treated as if the user submitted the form again?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  I first load the page. Then I click on a date and a form appears. Then I fill that form and then the page automatically refreshes and echo output appears. Then if I manually refresh the page, then also the echo output appears. So does this mean that if a user submits a form once and then refreshes the page, it will be treated as if the user submitted the form again?

Comment: Yes, when you refresh a post in a browser it re-sends the POST request completely. In fact, browsers usually warn you when they are about to do this.

Comment: @JohnReid So, what is the solution? I don't want this to be happening.

Comment: You can use a header redirect to reload the page after performing your POST-related functions. I'll post some examples.

Comment: If you refresh the page you get after you submitted the form you actually submit the form again and the browser requires your confirmation before doing it. There is no surprise here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the form. A POST request is sent to the server.

You can avoid this by redirecting the page once you have completed the work that your script is doing with this:

```
header("Location: http://mypage.php");
die();
```

Now, the problem here is that you lose echoing data data, so you could add something to give a success message:

```
header("Location: http://mypage.php?success=true");
die();
```

Now, in your script you could have this where the output would go:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['success'] && $_GET['success'] == 'true' ) ) {
    echo 'Your form has been submitted!';
}
```

This should avoid the trouble that you're having. There are other techniques though and you should use one that's right for you.

On a side note, POST requests are also resubmitted when you use forward and back buttons in your browser - you should be mindful of this, too.

Comment: Other techniques include using sessions and / or unique URLs - but I don't want to get into that in this specific answer.